# How do you refresh or rebuild the cached list of suggested references in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I import an existing class by doing alt+enter on a word in intellij-idea code editor.  This displays two references to two classes as suggestions to be imported.

Currently that list of references is wrong.  How do you force a refresh or rebuild of that cached import list?

[image]

(both classes are in the same project and only one of them has a class with the same name as the one that I've done alt+enter on...it is clearly confused!)

What I've tried already

- flutter clean
- restarted the analysis server
- pub get
- restarted idea
- intellij idea restart and invalidate caches

but none of those worked

**Edit**
deleted .dartServer folder worked

Comment: Have you tried "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: thank you for your input @y.bedrov but unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: You may also try to close the IDE and delete the ~./dartServer folder

Comment: perfect, thank you @y.bedrov, that worked!